# LTI variable substitution for Student Enrolment date in Moodle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, moodle, lti

The Ruby on Rails app I'm working on is a Tool Provider (TP) of Learning Tools Interoperability (LTI) version 1.1. One of our consumer uses Moodle 3.4 version. I need to get the student enrolment dates to a course from the Moodle instance to the provider as a launch param. Is there any LTI variable substitutions can I use to get this information ?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: 'no'.

Better answer:
The list of spec defined LTI variables can be found at https://www.imsglobal.org/spec/lti/v1p3/#lti-context-variable

and I don't see any variables that look like they would directly match what you need.  And of note moodle doesn't actually send *all* of the possible variables, you can find the list of variables moodle *does* support by referencing this file in the project's github.

https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/ltiprovider/src/ToolProvider/ToolProvider.php

It is common where different platforms may allow variables to be sent that are in addition to those defined by the specification, but in this case it does not seem that moodle sends what you are looking for.

In the LTI 1.3 specification you might want to look at the Names and Roles Provisioning service (http://www.imsglobal.org/spec/lti-nrps/v2p0), however it still doesn't provide specific dates for the events, but does allow detections of adds and drops. Also there is a delta portion of the spec so you can load 'changes since' the last polling period.